# Generate perfect side-view image from inclined view

Tags: computer-vision

I have several images of cylindrically symmetric objects. One example is shown below.

[image]

This picture was taken viewing the object at a slight (unknown) tilt. I want perfect side-view of this image. In this side view image, there would be no ellipses visible (red) in the mid-section and the bottom boundary will be perfectly flat (not bowed downward). Is there any technique in classical computer vision (CV) which will help me?

Context: My end goal is a radius `r` value as a function of `z` (which is pointing up in the plane of the paper) and my plan is to get an orthographic transform and get a list of points from the right half of the edge.

Alternatively, I can compute the tilt angle knowing the major and the minor exes of the highlighted red ellipse. But I'm lost on how to detect that ellipse in the first place. So any pointers in that direction would also be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple shape, you only need to calibrate the camera and resolve the image scale, for example by having an object of known size in the image that can be auto-detected. After identifying the horizontal plane, you can lift it and intersect with the object to determine ellipses of known size. I believe most of what you need can be found in Antonio Criminisi's old papers or PhD thesis from his time at Oxford.

For a general shape, you need a 3D reconstruction (model) of the object. If the shape is convex (as in your example), and easily segmented (matted) from the background, reconstruction from silhouette intersections is the way to go. See Szelinsky's papers from the 90's, and various commercial implementations of the idea. Stereo and/or structured lighting is another possibility.

Comment: I'm working with pre-existing photos. Re-taking them with a calibration target is not an available option. My approach so far has been to detect an `r(z)` curve and spin it around the `z` axis. But the non-side-view images complicate the picture. E.g. two stacked cubes (smaller cube on top of a larger one) will result in a trapezoid. If you strongly feel what I'm asking is not possible, please feel free to mention it, so I can accept the answer.